# StackOverFlowException в пользовательском элементе

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol, stackoverflow

Очень часто мне необходимо в элементе DataGridView отображать по умолчанию вертикальный скролбар. Для этих целей я использую простенький расширитель для стандартного контрола.

```
internal partial class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    internal CustomDataGridView() : base()
    {
        this.VerticalScrollBar.Visible = true;
        this.VerticalScrollBar.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(VerticalScrollBar_VisibleChanged);
    }

    internal void VerticalScrollBar_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.VerticalScrollBar.Visible)
        {
            this.VerticalScrollBar.Location = new Point(this.ClientRectangle.Width - this.VerticalScrollBar.Width - 1, 1);
            this.VerticalScrollBar.Height = this.ClientRectangle.Height - 2;
            this.VerticalScrollBar.Width = this.VerticalScrollBar.Width;
            this.VerticalScrollBar.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Недавно заметил что при повторном заполнении CustomDataGridView вываливается непонятно откуда появляющееся сообщение. Частота появления непредсказуема. Может 20 раз обновиться без проблем, а может при первом же обновлении выдать это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код работы с контролом такой:

```
    public void writeNameTable(NameTable NameTable)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new writeNameTableDelegate(writeNameTable), new object[] { NameTable });
            return;
        }

        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

        NAME_TABLE = NameTable.NAMES;
        for (int i = 0; i < NAME_TABLE.Length; i++)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);

            int index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);

            this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = i.ToString();
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = NAME_TABLE[i].Name;
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = ((ObjectFlags)NAME_TABLE[i].ObjectFlag).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Вопрос: как отловить/исправить подобное исключение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StackOverflowException` невозможно отловить. Это исключение возникает, когда текущий поток далее не может работать из-за переполнения стека. То есть данное исключение в любом случае приводит к падению приложения.

Всё что можно сделать - это исправить код, чтобы данный тип исключений не возникал. Для анализа причин исключения изучите трассировку стека, там должна быть цепочка рекурсивных вызовов, которая поможет понять изначальную причину.

Вероятно причиной появления исключения является другой обработчик этого же события `VisibleChanged` который выполняет действие, обратное текущему, для этого либо родительского контрола. Я бы не рекомендовал меняеть `Visible` в этом обработчике, не вижу причин для вызова `Show()`.

У вас примерно такая рекурсия

```
void Method1()
{
    Method2();
}

void Method2();
{
    Method1();
}
```

Если в этом примере вызвать любой из методов, будет `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение про бесконечную рекурсию. Проблему этим удалось локализовать и оказалось что она возникает при **dataGridView.Rows.Clear()**. Думаю добавить пользовательский метод обработки очистки строк элемента с учётом их видимости. Т.е. как-то при создании элемента автоматически добавлять невидимую строку чтобы она оставалась всегда в массиве строк и не давала вызывать **ScrollBarVisibleChanged** повторно.

Comment: @Rootware скорей всего так и есть.

Comment: ответ меня устраивает полностью. Проблему локализовал банальным триггером чтобы избежать рекурсии. Вроде работает.